# Estimate mean and variance from multiple realizations of Gaussian process

Tags: estimation, gaussian-process

I have a certain number of realizations of the same Gaussian process. I want to get the mean and the variance of this process. How can I do that?

To better explain the question lets suppose I have my data in this from.

```
Data=[array_of_samples_extrated_from_process_at_time_1;
      array_of_samples_extrated_from_process_at_time_2;
      array_of_samples_extrated_from_process_at_time_3;
      ....
     ];
```

Comment: Why can you not simply calculate the mean and standard deviation at each time point? Or does the mean follow some kind of ARIMA process?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to tackle this including Product of Experts (PoE), Generalised Product of Experts (gPoE), Bayesian Committee Machines (BCM), Robust Bayesian Committee Machines (rBCM). All of these methods assume independence between the gaussian processes and differ with regard to weighting the GPs (known as local experts) based on heuristics and / or removing the accumulative weighting of the prior.

Anyway, Marc Deisenroth gives a good description of them in his [ICML paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20181103180333/https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk:8443/bitstream/10044/1/22230/8/icml2015.pdf)    last year. The equations are literally just a few lines of code too which is nice ;)

Comment: I'm not sure this is a quality answer. It's not clear that the assumption of independence applies. As-is this is a kind of "link only" answer. The paper is focused on "big data" applications. At least, if 4 or 5 TLAs are invoked, provide some overview of which works best when.